# How to check a string is a class or an ID then strip them off to get the name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring, indexof

How can I check a string is a class or an ID then strip them off to get the name? For instance,

```
$string = ".isclass"; 
$string = "#isid";

if($($string).indexOf('.') != -1)) alert($($string).substring(1));
```

Comment: that is even better! thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know if the string starts with a `.` or `#` and then use the remained, you could use `String.match()` like so:

```
if (matches = $string.match(/^([.#])(.+)/)) {
    // matches[1] will contain either . or #
    alert(matches[2]);
} else {
    // it's something else
}
```

Answer (score 2):

why not just use a regex, then you don't have to worry if it's a class or a id

```
$string.replace(/^(\.|#)/,'') // will replace .class to class - #class to class
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FcM2Y/

Comment: You should consider `(/^(.|#)/` instead (if you only want to remove characters from the start). What should `.element.myclass` return?

Comment: `'dots match most chars'.replace(/(.|#)/,'') // "ots match most chars"`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure entirely what you want, but you can have select predefined settings depending on what you find by using an object, e.g.

```
var $string = ".isclass";

var dict = {
    '.' : 'class',
    '#' : 'id'

}, out;
if ($string[0] in dict) out = dict[$string[0]] + ', ' + $string.slice(1);
else out = 'no match, ' + $string;
console.log(out); // "class, isclass"
```

Comment: @lauthiamkok [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/object-vs-regex-1-char) showing `in` operator with an object then `.slice(1)` to be faster than regexp.